# How do I select multiple values in an array?

Tags: c#, arrays

```
int[] numbers = new int[] 
{ 
    1, 2, 33, 44, 55, 68, 77, 96, 100 
};

if (numbers[] % 2 == 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("EVEN");
}
```

I want to make the code say even when the value in the array is an even number.
How could I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need [loop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/for)

```
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
{
  if (numbers[i] % 2 == 0)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("EVEN");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your question is *vague* one:

> ...the code say even when the value in the array is an even number

You may want to query `numbers` (with a help of *Linq*):

If array contains *at least one* even value:

```
 using System.Linq;

 ...

 if (numbers.Any(item => item % 2 == 0))
   Console.WriteLine("EVEN");
```

If array values are *all* even:

```
 if (numbers.All(item => item % 2 == 0))
   Console.WriteLine("EVEN");
```

Obtain `even` values (let's have an `int[] even` array):

```
 int[] even = numbers
   .Where(item => item % 2 == 0)
   .ToArray();

 if (even.Length > 0) 
   Console.WriteLine($"EVEN: {string.Join(", ", even)}");
```

Finally, you may want to *scan* the `numbers` array and do something on each even item:

```
  foreach (int item in numbers) {
    if (item % 2 == 0) {
      Console.WriteLine("EVEN:");  
    } 
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it:

```
var evenNumbers = numbers.Where(x => x % 2 == 0).ToArray();
```